# Can I Dynamically Update HTML Over a Web Socket?

Tags: perl, websocket

I'm new to web sockets, and I'm building a web GUI around a command line interface that talks to IoT devices. Some of the commands take several seconds to run because I'm sending them to a large network of devices.

It would be very helpful if I could pass the individual device responses to a textarea (resembling a terminal window) as the responses come in.

I'm using a web socket connection between the client and server. Here is a simplified example of the effect I'm trying to achieve.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/' => 'index';

websocket '/get_loop' => sub {

    my $c = shift;

    $c->app->log->debug("Websocket opened");

    $c->on(message => sub {

        my ($c, $msg) = @_;

        for (my $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $c->send("$i\n");
            $c->app->log->debug("$i\n");
            sleep (1);
        };
    });

    $c->on(finish => sub {
        my ($c, $code, $reason) = @_;
        $c->app->log->debug("WebSocket closed with status $code");
    });
};

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep
<html>
<head>
    <title>Websocket Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        textarea {
            height: 200px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Websocket Test</h1>
    <textarea id="terminal" readonly></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:3000/get_loop');
        var terminal = document.getElementById('terminal');
        ws.onopen = function() {
            ws.send('start');
        };
        ws.onmessage = function(event) {
            var msg = event.data;
            terminal.innerHTML += msg;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, I have a loop counting from 0 to 14. I'm trying to send each count to the textarea via the web socket for display as the loop counts up. The loop simulates the CLI responses in my actual application. Is this even possible to do over a web socket?

-EDIT-

Modifying the above web socket code and using `Mojo::IOLoop->recurring` solves the problem without having to resort to multithreading.

```
websocket '/get_loop' => sub {

    my $c = shift;

    $c->app->log->debug("Websocket opened");

    my $id;
    $c->on(message => sub {

        my ($c, $msg) = @_;

        my $count = 0;
        $id = Mojo::IOLoop->recurring(1 => sub {
            $c->send("$count\n");
            $c->app->log->debug($count);
            sleep (1);
            $c->finish if $count++ == 10;
        });
    });

    $c->on(finish => sub {
        my ($c, $code, $reason) = @_;
        Mojo::IOLoop->remove($id);
        $c->app->log->debug("WebSocket closed with status $code");
    });
};
```

Comment: Yes, you can do it... should you do it? how you do it? these are project related specifics... Maybe pass raw data with the websocket and have formatting occur on the client side, or pass parsed HTML to the client from the server... (I would do A)... there are many different ways to do this.

Comment: The example I provided shows that I am passing data from the server to the client over the web socket. The problem is that the individual "counts" coming from the server do not get displayed in real time in the textarea as the server counts up from zero. Instead, the server spits out everything after the loop is complete. I should've made this more clear in my question. I'm having no trouble passing data to and fro the web socket, I just can't figure out how to send the data in real time while the server is in a loop.

Comment: Is there a specific problem with the code you show that you want help with?

Comment: That's because javascript is both evened and single-threaded - which means that `send` schedules an event that isn't processed until your code exits the loop. As long as your code is running, no other events are being processed. I'm simplifying the explanation, but the rule of thumb is "**assume that nothing happens before your code returns**". P.S. Oh, **oops**, I didn't notice the server was in `perl`, however, the same rule might apply...?

Comment: Sounds like a classic buffering issue. Have you tried replacing the `for` loop with a call to [`Mojo::IOLoop->recurring`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::IOLoop#recurring)?

Comment: Yes @Myst, I discussed this with a friend and I've learned that I cannot do what I want to do in a single thread. Your rule of thumb is helpful as I am clearly breaking this rule in my example. And yes, the server side code is written in Perl, and I'm using the Mojolicious framework.

Comment: Thank you @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I have not used `Mojo::IOLoop->recurring` before, but I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: Unfortunately `Mojo::IOLoop->recurring` is of no use. It simply invokes the callback repeatedly *after* the loop terminates. So if I were to try to use this in conjunction with a real world command like `$cmd = echo "tr -r" | nc 10.0.0.10 23` via `my @response = $ssh->capture($cmd)` none of the command response data will be passed back to the browser until the command finishes (just like the loop example provided). There is no real time data being sent back down the web socket. I believe the only way to do this sort of thing is to make it multithreaded.

Comment: "It simply invokes the callback repeatedly after the loop terminates" What loop? `recurring` is supposed to replace the loop, not be called inside it.

Comment: Not tracking you @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, can you provide an example?

Comment: Delete the `for` loop and replace it with `my $id = Mojo::IOLoop->recurring(1 => sub {...});`, and put what was inside the loop into the sub (except for the `sleep`, which you can delete).

Comment: Thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, your suggestion is very helpful. I've edited my OP with a solution using `Mojo::IOLoop->recurring` in case anyone else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 2):

you need to make javascript websocket listener on the page and insert the data passed into the DOM.

```
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    socket.send('Hello Server!');
});

socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    var div = document.getElementById('divID');
    div.innerHTML = event.data;
});
```

oh I see, your question is about the server Perl code. What I suggest is making a static array of connections in in the Perl, assigning them on open event, deassigning them on close event. You shouldn't need to send the data back in the on message sub. You could use Event::Lib $event->add( [$timeout] )  and then enumerate over the open sockets (to various different web clients) calling the $c->send("$i\n"); it's totally asynchronous, so no need to tie this to an on message sub. The server can do it whenever it wants.

Make static variable in PERL:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=8299